# deal with dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp

I am a begginer in NLP and I want to do a preprocessing in a dataset which has the following form

```
dataset = {'key1': [{ 'x1': '...', 'x2': '...', 'x3': '...' }], 'key2': [...], ....}
```

First of all I want to create a list which contains all the values of 'x2', such as

```
dataset_list = [[value of 'x2' of key1], [value of 'x2' of key2], ...]
```

Could you please help you know can I do it?

Comment: You've described the process correctly; now write the code.  teaching you how to iterate through a dict is something you get from a tutorial, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each key of your dictionary has a `list` which contains a `dict`.

- First, you access the list using `dataset[key]`
- Then, you access the dict using `dataset[key][0]`, the first element of the list.
- Lastly, to access the value of x2 in this dictionary, you use `dataset[key][0]['x2']`.

Putting this together into a list comprehension, you would get this:

```
dataset_list = [dataset[k][0]['x2'] for k in dataset]
```

Comment: Why does this work?

Comment: @PeterWood - Explained, thanks!

Comment: Thanks lot Peter, I have one more question why you have access on keys by writing 'for k in dataset'? for me 'for k in dataset.keys()' makes more sense.

Comment: @George - Iterating using `for k in dataset` automatically accesses the keys. As an aside, you should really brush up your Python basics a LOT before moving into something complicated like NLP.

Comment: You could alternatively say `[value[0]['x2'] for value in dataset.values()]`